# Is the phrase "all my breath and being" an established idiom?

Tags: idioms

I read a sentence in a chapter in my book which was:

> And I studied hard, **with all my breath and being**, in a frenzy almost.

Is the highlighted phrase an established idiom. I am asking this because I didn't find any dictionary describing it and would I be wrong if I used in a casual conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling to find much on this particular phrase in this exact form. (Just 3 texts) I'm not familiar with it as such, but I think I get the gist of it.

I think it's very much akin to:

> Every fibre/fiber of my being

or simply:

> My entire being

In that your entire self (with no exception - including breath) is devoted to this task - no distractions whatsoever.

[Entire Being](https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/my+entire+being)

Answer (score 0):

It is not an established phrase, but it is a very evocative description. It alludes to common phrases like "to my dying breath" and "every fiber of my being".